# Angular 9 Unhandled Promise rejection: Angular JIT compilation failed error

Tags: angular

I upgraded our app to Angular 9 yet in production testing I am getting this error. I am serving my app with the command `ng serve --optimization=true --aot=true --prod` before I deploy this to production and its just not working

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
  - JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping. ; Zone: <root> ;
```

This is pointing to my polyfills.ts

I have added import "@angular/compiler to the top of my main.ts file with no luck.

I have also removed all the imports from polyfill except for zone.js and still get the error.

What does this mean and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Try to compile for production with `ng build --prod` and serve with something like `lite-server`, as [per docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#building-and-serving-from-disk).

Comment: Compiling isn't the problem its running the application where the error appears. I deployed it to a test server that mimics our production environment and its the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import '@angular/compiler' at the very top of your main.ts file but since you already have that then

You have to run this in your package.json

```
scripts{
"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es5 browser module main --first-only"
}
```

Comment: It takes non-Ivy libraries and generates files which Ivy understands. 
If no properties are given, ngcc will process all package formats (fesm2015, fesm5, es2015, esm2015, esm5, main, module), which may not be what's desired.
The Flag first-only tells ngcc to process the first property it finds in package.json, otherwise it'll process all entries listed above. And create-ivy-entry-points will tell ngcc to create new properties for the Ivy generated entry, instead of overwriting the previous one